# can't find qtcreator in linux mint repository

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde, qt

I am brand new to linux, so pardon the ignorance. I recently installed Linux Mint 15 KDE edition, and i'm trying to install qtcreator. From what little i know of linux, i am to obtain software packages from a repository. In mint, i have the Software Manager application open, and when i search qtcreator or any combination of qt, nothing comes up. I also noticed that there is only 2000+ applications available. Did mint not set my software sources entirely? if not, what repositories should i be looking for. I was also looking for chromium, and that didn't exist either. I desperately want to stop using windows, but not being able to find programs along with some other issues, is making it very difficult for me.

EDIT: @Chris, i ran the update command and i got a TON of errors. Here is the output.

```
gawain-MS-7640 gawain # apt-get update
Get:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia Release.gpg [197 B]
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Get:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia Release [17.7 kB]                   
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Get:3 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main amd64 Packages [23.5 kB]       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia Release.gpg                               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security Release.gpg                     
Get:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream amd64 Packages [9,249 B]   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com olivia Release.gpg                            
Get:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import amd64 Packages [39.0 kB]     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates Release.gpg                       
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security Release                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com olivia Release                                
Get:6 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main i386 Packages [23.5 kB]        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia Release                                   
Get:7 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream i386 Packages [9,237 B]    
Get:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import i386 Packages [39.9 kB]      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates Release                           
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia Release.gpg                           
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia Release                               
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import Translation-en_US              
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import Translation-en                 
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main Translation-en_US                
Err http://archive.canonical.com olivia/partner amd64 Packages                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main Translation-en                   
Err http://archive.canonical.com olivia/partner i386 Packages                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream Translation-en_US            
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream Translation-en               
Ign http://archive.canonical.com olivia/partner Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com olivia/partner Translation-en                 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/main amd64 Packages             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/universe amd64 Packages         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/main i386 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/restricted i386 Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/universe i386 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia/free amd64 Packages                   
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/main Translation-en             
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia/non-free amd64 Packages               
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/multiverse Translation-en_US    
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia/free i386 Packages                    
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia/non-free i386 Packages                
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/restricted Translation-en_US    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/restricted Translation-en       
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/universe Translation-en_US      
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia/free Translation-en_US                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com olivia-security/universe Translation-en         
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia/free Translation-en                   
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia/non-free Translation-en_US            
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org olivia/non-free Translation-en               
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/main amd64 Packages                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com olivia-updates/universe Translation-en
Fetched 162 kB in 17s (9,272 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/olivia-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/olivia/free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/olivia/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/olivia/free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/olivia/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

i have not installed or done anything at all to this fresh install of Mint with KDE. Is this something people always deal with right off the bat with linux?

Comment: update your package-list `apt-get update`. Now there should be more

Comment: Try the following: First run: `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -fv` than run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: exact same error dialog. No dice :\ . After installing mint, was there any steps i needed to take before installing software? when i said i had done nothing, i mean the first thing i did after loading mint for the first time was open the software manager and look for chromium, qtcreator, and mumble, of which i found none :\

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install qcreator without the software-manager. Follow this tutorial to download and install it:

> First download Qt 5.0.1 from http://qt-project.org/downloads. I'm
>   using a 32bit machine so I'll select that and download the file
>   qt-linux-opensource-5.0.1-x86-offline.run. To install the .run file,
>   right click for terminal in the directory containing the installer and
>   type:
>
> `chmod u+x qt-linux-opensource-5.0.1-x86-offline.run`
>   `sudo ./qt-linux-opensource-5.0.1-x86-offline.run`
>
> Let it install with all default settings.(update: In Mint 15 with Qt
>   5.0.2, it’s default installation directory is /home/username/Qt5.0.2. It’s weird to put it there so I’d recommend changing it to
>   /opt/Qt5.0.2)
>
> Now if you just try to run Qt Creator now you'll realize you can't
>   open the application(update: this seems to be fixed with Qt 5.0.2… or
>   Mint 15). That's because there seems to be some faulty linking problem
>   thing going on. To fix this, you'll create your own custom launcher.
>
> Right click your desktop and select "Create Launcher...".
>
> - Type = Location
> - Name = Qt Creator
> - Location = /opt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
>
> now if you navigate to the qt5 directory and type "png" you will be
>   able to find the Qt Creator logo. Just drag and drop it to that red
>   rocket, press "ok" and you have your launcher set up.
>
> Now, you should be able to run Qt creator but unable to build and run
>   anything. That’s because lots of dependencies are missing. You would
>   think that by installing Qt 5.0.1 they would install the dependencies
>   as well but they don’t. Now open up the terminal and copy paste this:
>
> `sudo apt-get install build-essential sudo apt-get`
>   `install libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev`
>
> Now when you open Qt Creator it complains up to 3 times some .xml file
>   and no permission access denied thing and complains 3 times(exact same
>   things) when it closes. Strange problem. So navigate to your home
>   folder, reveal hidden files(Ctrl-H) and navigate to /.config/QtProject
>
> Open a terminal there and type
>
> `sudo chown -R username qtcreator`
>
> And so, there you have it. Qt 5.0.1 and Qt Creator 2.6.2 running
>   happily.
>
> Now if you do use the examples(opt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc/examples), you'll
>   realized that you do not have permission to access it. Why? I don't
>   know. But to change it go to "opt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc" right click and
>   open terminal and type
>
> `sudo chown -R username examples`
>
> Where "username" is the name of the user you wish to transfer full
>   permissions to.

[Source](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=127051)